# Run CAML Query on DataTable SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, sharepoint-library, datatable

I have a DataTable having Some rows. Is there any way to execute CAML Query on it.

Or Alternatively, How can I convert this DataTable into a SPList so tha CAML can be executed on SPList.

```
private DataTable Process(DataTable d, string s)
{
    DataTable dd = d;
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    query.Query = s;
    query.ViewAttributes = "Scope = 'RecursiveAll'";
    DataTable dtSearch = new DataTable();
    SPList Dest = new SPList();


    dtSearch = d.GetItems(query).GetDataTable();
    return dtSearch;
}
```

In above Code d.GetItems can not be done. ???

Solution tried:

I tried this from technet.

```
private SPList dtConvertSPList(DataTable dt)
{
    SPList newList = null;
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepointvm"))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {



                Guid newListGuid = web.Lists.Add("TempList", "This is my temp list, it will be removed when used", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
                newList = web.Lists[newListGuid];

                if (newList != null)
                {
                    /* Loop through the datatable and add columns to the list */
                    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        newList.Fields.Add(dc.ColumnName, SPFieldType.Text, false);
                    }

                    /* Update the list to get the new fields */
                    newList.Update();


                    /* Populate the list from the datatable */
                    SPListItem newItem = null;
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        /* Create a new item in the list */
                        newItem = newList.Items.Add();
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            newItem[dc.ColumnName] = row[dc].ToString();
                            newItem.Update();

                        }


                    }
                }
           }
    }
    return newList;

}
```

But the problem being faced by me is: the outer for loop i.e.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        /* Create a new item in the list */
                        newItem = newList.Items.Add();
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            newItem[dc.ColumnName] = row[dc].ToString();
                            newItem.Update();

                        }

                    }
```

this outer loop is executing only once out of surprise.

*Debug Findings: The DataTable passed to this function had 3358 records. newList is created Fine with all columns but only one row that too with incomplete information in its columns.

Improvement Needed:

The loop should work fine and where should i put the code to delete this newList after returnig it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess newItem.update() should be outside of inner for loop.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        /* Create a new item in the list */
                        newItem = newList.Items.Add();
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            newItem[dc.ColumnName] = row[dc].ToString();
                        }
                        newItem.Update();    
                    }
```

Also why you want to run caml query on datatable? You can use [datatable.select()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) to query on datatable.

Comment: Even that did not work .

Comment: Is you are getting any error message? Also why not you are directly do query on Datatable?

Comment: How do i query dataTable with a single keyword on each row + all the columns.

Comment: I have not tried this, but i guess this is as per your requirement: https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()